# Разделяемая память

Tags: c++, winapi

Подскажите, как реализовать разделяемую память через `CreateFileMapping` и `MapViewOfFile`. Нужно, чтобы было две программы, т.е. 2 запущенные консоли и между ними было взаимодействие. Т.е. клиент и сервер. Например, один печатает у себя, и у другого то же самое должно напечататься и наоборот.

Comment: Вы хотите действительно кроссплатформенное решение?

Comment: объяснение: потому что `MapViewOfFile` — это функция WinAPI. То есть вам если вы её используете, ваш код не пойдёт под Linux, например.

Comment: Даже если кроссплатформенное решение не нужно, то лучше всё равно делать с помощью `boost::shared_memory`. В документации есть хорошие примеры.

Comment: Нет, нужно только для винды, и только через WinAPI.

Comment: если через winapi то взгляните на функцию sendmesage она может отправлять сообщение в другое приложение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких целей разделяемая память не очень подходит, т.к. не имеет механизма уведомлений. Это именно что разделяемый кусок памяти, в который можно писать с разных процессов. Для целей указанных в вовпросе лучше подходят пайпа(pipes). На MSDN есть [пример](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365588(v=vs.85).aspx) построения клиент-серверного приложения, т.е. как раз то, что Вам нужно.

А если всё таки очень хочется делать через разделяемую память, то на том же MSDN есть замечательный [пример](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx), как пользоваться функциями из вопроса. Вам же остается с одной стороны писать в разделяемый кусок, а с другой - проверять, на наличие новых данных. Или ввести некий синхронизирующий примитив, типа именованного семафора, чтобы не заниматься постоянной проверкой, которая отъедает ресурсы ЦП впустую.

Comment: Спасибо. Про пайп я знаю. Вторую ссылку сейчас буду изучать.

Answer (score 2):

Разделяемая память делается просто - вызовами `CreateFileMapping` и `MapViewOfFile`. Допустим у нас есть структура которая будет жить в общей памяти

```
struct SharedData {
    ...
    char text[1024];
};
```

Тогда мы создаем глобальный именованный объект общей памяти

```
mapping = ::CreateFileMappingW(
        nullptr, // без файла на диске
        nullptr, // не наследуется процессами-потомками
        PAGE_READWRITE,
        0, sizeof(SharedData), // размер
        L"Local\\test-shared-memory");
```

и берем его память

```
data = (SharedData*)::MapViewOfFile(mapping, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
```

Хендл `mapping` должен жить до конца работы с общей памятью. Если его закрыть, то память на которую указывает `data` останется жить, но будет отвязана от общей памяти.

Когда общая память будет не нужна - надо вызвать `::UnmapViewOfFile(data);` и `::CloseHandle(mapping);`, в любом порядке. (Или `ExitProcess`, при завершении процесса всё закрывается само).

Чтобы не вызывать их вручную, можно воспользоваться умными указателями:

```
std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(&::CloseHandle)> mapping(
    ::CreateFileMappingW(...),
    ::CloseHandle);
std::unique_ptr<SharedData, decltype(&::UnmapViewOfFile)> data(
    (SharedData*)::MapViewOfFile(mapping.get(), FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0),
    ::UnmapViewOfFile);
```

Если запустить несколько процессов, то первый процесс вызвавший `CreateFileMapping` создаст глобальный объект, а остальные будут получать его хендл. Изменения `data` в одном процессе будут видны в остальных, но чтобы предотвратить гонки нужна какая-то синхронизация. В идеале нужен multiple readers/single-writer mutex и condition variable, но в Windows они не умеют работать с несколькими процессами, по этому все средства синхронизации надо писать самому. Реализация правильной межпроцессной синхронизации в Windows выходит за рамки этого вопроса, по этому в примере ниже будет использован обычный polling.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>

struct SharedData {
    volatile unsigned long version;
    char text[1024];
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(&::CloseHandle)> mapping(
        ::CreateFileMappingW(nullptr, nullptr, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(SharedData), L"Local\\test-shared-memory"),
        ::CloseHandle);
    if (!mapping)
        return printf("CreateFileMapping error: %d\n", ::GetLastError());

    std::unique_ptr<SharedData, decltype(&::UnmapViewOfFile)> data(
        (SharedData*)::MapViewOfFile(mapping.get(), FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0),
        ::UnmapViewOfFile);
    if (!data)
        return printf("MapViewOfFile error: %d\n", ::GetLastError());

    std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(&::CloseHandle)> mutex(
        ::CreateMutexW(nullptr, FALSE, L"Local\\test-shared-memory-mutex"),
        ::CloseHandle);
    if (!mutex)
        return printf("CreateMutex error: %d\n", ::GetLastError());

    printf("Input 'new text' to change shared text, or 'exit' to exit\n\n");

    std::thread user_input_thread([&]{
        std::string new_text;
        while (std::getline(std::cin, new_text) && new_text != "exit") {
            ::WaitForSingleObject(mutex.get(), INFINITE);
            std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(&::ReleaseMutex)> lock(mutex.get(), ::ReleaseMutex);

            memcpy(data->text, new_text.c_str(), new_text.size() + 1);
            ::InterlockedIncrement(&data->version);
        }
    });

    auto current_version = data->version - 1;
    while (::WaitForSingleObject(user_input_thread.native_handle(), 200) != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        if (current_version == data->version)
            continue;

        current_version = data->version;

        ::WaitForSingleObject(mutex.get(), INFINITE);
        std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(&::ReleaseMutex)> lock(mutex.get(), ::ReleaseMutex);

        printf("Shared text: %s\n", data->text);
    }

    user_input_thread.join();
}
```

Comment: Ого! Оказывается, WinAPI можно скрестить с C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <windows.h>
#define  MAP_SIZE    64
#define  MAP_NAME    TEXT("MyConn")
#define  EVENT_NAME  TEXT("MyEvent")
#define  MUTEX_NAME  TEXT("MyMutex")
#define  CMD_QUIT    -1L
#define  CMD_THIS     1L

HANDLE g_event = NULL;
HANDLE g_mutex = NULL;
HANDLE g_map   = NULL;
char* g_buf   = NULL;
volatile LONG g_cmd = 0L;

DWORD initHandle(void);
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID arg);


int main(void){
   DWORD  err;

   if((err = initHandle()) != ERROR_SUCCESS){
       printf("error code: %08X\n", err);
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   HANDLE thd = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, NULL, 0, NULL);
   if(thd == NULL){
       printf("CreateThread, code: %08X\n", GetLastError());
       UnmapViewOfFile(g_buf);
       CloseHandle(g_map);
       CloseHandle(g_event);
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   puts("enter string");

   char  str[MAP_SIZE];
   int   len;
   DWORD ret;

   while(1){
       fgets(str, MAP_SIZE, stdin);
       fflush(stdin);

       len = lstrlenA(str);
       if(len > 0)
          str[--len] = '\0';
       if(! len)
           continue;

       if(! lstrcmpA(str, "exit")){
           g_cmd = CMD_QUIT;
           SetEvent(g_event);
           break;
       }

       ret = WaitForSingleObject(g_mutex, INFINITE);
       if(ret == WAIT_OBJECT_0){

            CopyMemory(g_buf, str, len + 1);
            FlushViewOfFile(str, len + 1);

            g_cmd = CMD_THIS;
            SetEvent(g_event);
            Sleep(100);
       }
       ReleaseMutex(g_mutex);
   }

   ret = WaitForSingleObject(thd, 3000);
   if(ret != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
       TerminateThread(thd, 0);
   CloseHandle(thd);

   CloseHandle(g_mutex);
   CloseHandle(g_event);
   UnmapViewOfFile(g_buf);
   CloseHandle(g_map);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


/*создание или открытие именованных объектов ядра: 
 MUTEX, EVENT, FileMapping */
DWORD initHandle(void){
   DWORD err;

   g_mutex = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, MUTEX_NAME);
   g_event = OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, EVENT_NAME);

   if((g_event == NULL) && (g_mutex == NULL)){

     g_mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, MUTEX_NAME);
     if(g_mutex == NULL)
         return GetLastError();

     g_event = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, EVENT_NAME);
     if(g_event == NULL){
         CloseHandle(g_mutex);
         return GetLastError();
     }

     g_map = CreateFileMapping((void*)INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 
                              PAGE_READWRITE, 0, MAP_SIZE, 
                              MAP_NAME);
     if(g_map == NULL){
         err = GetLastError();
         CloseHandle(g_mutex);
         CloseHandle(g_event);
         return err;
     }


     PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
     STARTUPINFO         si = {0};
     si.cb = sizeof(si);

     if(! CreateProcess(NULL, GetCommandLine(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 
         CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)){
         err = GetLastError();
         CloseHandle(g_mutex);
         CloseHandle(g_event);
         return err;
     }
     CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
     CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

  } else {
     g_map = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 
                             FALSE, MAP_NAME);

     if(g_map == NULL){
         err = GetLastError();
         CloseHandle(g_mutex);
         CloseHandle(g_event);
         return err;
     }
  }


  g_buf = (char*)MapViewOfFile(g_map, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE,0,0,0);
  if(g_buf == NULL){
     err = GetLastError();
     CloseHandle(g_mutex);
     CloseHandle(g_event);
     CloseHandle(g_map);
     return err;
  }
  return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}


//поток для чтение обновлёных данных
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID arg){
  BOOL   islp = TRUE;
  DWORD  ret;

  while(islp){

     ret = WaitForSingleObject(g_event, INFINITE);
     switch(ret){
     case WAIT_OBJECT_0:

         if(g_cmd == CMD_QUIT){
             islp = FALSE;
             continue;
         } else if(! g_cmd)
             printf("> %s\n", g_buf);
         g_cmd = 0L;

         ResetEvent(g_event);
         break;
     default:
         islp = FALSE;
         break;
     }
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```